# IOSink flush() interrupts the streaming from a Bluetooth device

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

We receive data every 0.01 seconds from the URL of the Bluetooth device after it is subscribed, but IOSink flush() causes interference which makes the interval longer (0.2 seconds etc). Any idea what could be causing this and/or would there be an alternative to IOSink? Now it is used to store data from the device to the phone.

This seems to happens on Android devices (iOS devices have not been tested).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.